# Android: Parse Json in Listview

Tags: android, json, listview

I have been trying to parse Json into A ListView but when i do so I get;

```
03-04 14:43:45.345: E/log_tag(16519): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: No value for items
```

It somehow can't get the items out of the Json Object.

Here's my code i used for it;

getJSON.java

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.util.Log;

    public class getJSON {

        public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){
            InputStream is = null;
            String result = "";
            JSONObject jArray = null;

            //http post
            try{
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

            }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("NO CONNECTION", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }

          //convert response to string
            try{
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result=sb.toString();
            }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("CANT CONVERT DATA", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }

            try{

                jArray = new JSONObject(result);            
            }catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.e("CANT READ DATA", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            }

            return jArray;
        }
}
```

and

the listview.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        //Get the data (see above)
        JSONObject json = getJSON.getJSONfromURL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UKFDubstep/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc");


               try{



                   final JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("items");

                        //Loop the Array
                for(int i=0;i < array.length();i++){                        

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject e = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                    map.put("title", "" + e.getString("title"));
                    map.put("viewCount", "Views: " +  e.getString("viewCount"));
                    mylist.add(map);
            }
               }catch(JSONException e)        {
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
               }

               ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.dubstep,
                       new String[] { "title", "viewCount" },
                       new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

       setListAdapter(adapter);

       final ListView lv = getListView();
       lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
       lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(dubstep.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });

    }
```

I have no idea where it went wrong.

Any help?
Thanks.

**EDIT:** json output

```
03-04 15:30:29.955: I/json(19109): {"error":{"message":"Response contains no content type","errors":[{"internalReason":"Response contains no content type","domain":"GData","code":"missingContentType"}],"code":400},"apiVersion":"2.1"}
```

Edit json link ;http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UKFDubstep/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc

Comment: Can you post the raw JSON string you have as well? It seems the JSON you have is not the same format as you expected.

Comment: I see a url in there -- I think you're going to want to do your network activity off of the UI thread. and I have no idea how your JSON package works but "items" is nested within "data" -- do you need to reference it in a nested fashion, "data.items" maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the JSON result (by opening your example url) I see that 'items' is inside another JSONObject. So I believe you need to do:

```
JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject('data');
JSONArray array = data.getJSONArray('items');
```

Comment: Then i get this ; getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection and no value for data

Comment: Can you post the exact Exception you get? What you could try to do is simply print to LogCat json.toString() so you can see and make sure that it actually has all the data you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need getJSON.java, only you should do to make it work is this:

```
    private static String URL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UKFDubstep/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        try{                   
               HttpClient  httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
               HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
               HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
               HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
               String _response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); // content will be consume only once
               Log.i(".......",_response);
               JSONObject json = new JSONObject(_response);
               JSONArray jarray = json.getJSONArray("items");                     
                    //Loop the Array
               for(int i=0;i < array.length();i++){                        

                   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                   JSONObject e = array.getJSONObject(i);

                   map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                   map.put("title", "" + e.getString("title"));
                   map.put("viewCount", "Views: " +  e.getString("viewCount"));
                   mylist.add(map);
        }
           }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
           }

           ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.dubstep,
                   new String[] { "title", "viewCount" },
                   new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

   setListAdapter(adapter);

   final ListView lv = getListView();
   lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(dubstep.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        }
    });

}
```

But you should now that, parsing JSON data should not be executed in UI thread. You need to extend AsyncTask and do that job there in doInBackgound() method, so you can do parsing in seperate thread, not in UI...[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)