# Parsing Youtube Gdata json into ListView

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I have been trying to find a working example of "Parsing Youtube Gdata JSON" in Android to populate a listview.

I have been reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555511/android-parse-json-in-listview), and I almost have it working except for 4 errors..

1. item_title
2. item_subtitle
3. setListAdapter
4. getListView

   ```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.ListAdapter;
   import android.widget.ListView;
   import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
   import android.widget.Toast;
   import org.json.JSONArray;
   import org.json.JSONException;
   import org.json.JSONObject;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.HashMap;

   public class listview extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

   //Get the data (see above)
   JSONObject json = getJSON.getJSONfromURL("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=random&max-results=50&v=2&alt=jsonc");


   try{



       final JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("items");

       //Loop the Array
       for(int i=0;i < array.length();i++){

           HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
           JSONObject e = array.getJSONObject(i);

           map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
           map.put("title", "" + e.getString("title"));
           map.put("viewCount", "Views: " +  e.getString("viewCount"));
           mylist.add(map);
       }
   }catch(JSONException e)        {
       Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
   }

          ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.dubstep,
                  new String[] { "title", "viewCount" },
                  new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

   setListAdapter(adapter);

   final ListView lv = getListView();
   //final ListView lv = getListView();
   lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
           HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
           Toast.makeText(listview.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
   });

   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.listview, menu);
       return true;
       }
   }
   ```

It says `"Cannot resolve symbol 'item_title' and 'item_subtitle'`
and
`"Cannot resolve method 'setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)'`

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: where is `item_title` in your code? can you post the same? post some more relevant code.

Comment: you mean this? `new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });`

Comment: post the whole code and the stack trace.

Comment: I am relatively new to Android programming, but how do I get the stack trace?

Comment: you can check the updated answer. But it is better to extract the url of the bitmap and do lazy loading. to view logcat goto windows open pepresctive. goto others. open ddms. logcat.

Comment: Robert de Jonge did you try the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your activity class does not extend `ListActivity`. Hence the errors 3 and 4

You should use `AsyncTask` for network related operation. You cannot run network related operation on the main ui thread.

You should use lazy loading for images. But for sample i have use a ArrayList of bitmaps for thumbnail. You might run into memory leaks. So use lazy loading. Modify the below according to your requirement.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> msg = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Bitmap> thumb = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Loading..");
        b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new TheTask().execute();
            }

       });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void getData()
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=random&max-results=50&v=2&alt=jsonc");
        // HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mbbangalore/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc");     
        try
        {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); // content will be consume only once

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(_response);

        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("items");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String title1 = jsonObject.getString("title");
            title.add(title1);
            String thumbUrl = jsonObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("sqDefault");
            URL url1 = new URL(thumbUrl);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url1.openConnection().getInputStream());
            thumb.add(bmp);
            String url;
            try {

                url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
                msg.add(url);
            } catch (JSONException ignore) {
            }
        }
        } 
        catch(Exception e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
  class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
  {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
        YouTubeAdapter you = new YouTubeAdapter(MainActivity.this,msg,title,thumb);
        lv.setAdapter(you);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getData();
        return null;
    }

  }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
       />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

YouTubeAdapter

```
public class YouTubeAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context mContext;
    Intent intent;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ArrayList<String> mVideo= new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> mTitle= new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Bitmap> mThumb= new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    public YouTubeAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> a,ArrayList title,ArrayList thumb)  {
        mContext=context;
        mVideo=a;   
        mTitle = title;
        mThumb= thumb;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mVideo.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ViewHolder vh;

        if(arg1==null)
        {
            arg1=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.video, null);
            vh= new ViewHolder();
            vh.tv=(TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.tvv);
            vh.iv=(ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.ivv);
            arg1.setTag(vh);
        }
        else
        {
            vh= (ViewHolder)arg1.getTag();
        }
        vh.tv.setText(mTitle.get(position));
        vh.iv.setImageBitmap(mThumb.get(position));
        return arg1;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView iv;
    }   
}
```

video.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Snap shot

[image]

Comment: I get these errors though..
`cannot find symbol variable tvv`, `cannot find symbol variable ivv` and `cannot find symbol variable video` I created `video.xml` in the layouts folder

Comment: @RobertdeJonge  it's the id of the textview in `video.xml`. So check if you have video.xml and textviews inside them

Comment: @RobertdeJonge create a file `video.xml` in your res folder and paste the above `video.xml` code inside it

Comment: I copied it as you posted it, I have `tvv` and `ivv` in the `video.xml` in the `layout` folder what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @RobertdeJonge if you do as above i don't see why it won't work coz i tried and then posted the snap shot. post the updated code

Comment: I haven't made any changes to the code that you posted, I want to get it to work first, and then look into making changes

Comment: @RobertdeJonge if you can post your updated code may be i can find the cause of the error.

Comment: I redid it in a new solution, and that seemed to work fine, I don't know what went wrong, but it's working now, is there a way that it saves the data when you go from landscape view to portrait view? that's the only thing I need help with.. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Raghunandan, I got the code working fine even with a variable in the URL to allow for other keywords, but I have one question, how do I get the video URL as a variable to pass to a fullscreen activity? I am able to open the activity through "intent" I just need to pass the URL to it, and I can figure the rest out, if you can help me with that it would be awesome :)