# how can i play playlist videos from listview of playlist service in android

Tags: android

am able to get the channel palylist service from youtube API.i want to parse that service using json and display all videos in that playlist in listview and finally when am click on particular list item it will play video.
 thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes you can. So what is the problem? Have you tried anything so far???

Comment: yes am trying to get playlist service from youtube api. but i want to parse that service using json parsing and display videos in listview.

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/akoscz/YouTubePlaylist

Comment: Why? What it shows???

Comment: am getting the videos of youtube playlst and am showing that videos in listview. now, i want to play video when click on particular listitem.

Comment: hi am showing the channel playlist from youtube api json service is in listview. but i want to display video when click on particular list item based on position. i want that source code. please any one can provide.

Comment: Am getting different video id with using youtube json parsing when click on listview items. But Only one video id is appended to youtube playerview. i want to play video when click on particular item on listview. please provide source code.

Answer (score 0):

you can check in example provided in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications) so start with this example and then if you find any difficulty then you can ask.. also check this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348453/parsing-youtube-gdata-json-into-listview)